# Why is img src not working as <asp:Image ImageUrl does

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm currently trying to get an `img` tag to show the image by settings its `src` property.

I was using an `asp:ImageButton` as:

```
asp:ImageButton ID="image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "Images/" + Eval("CarMakeId") + ".jpg" %>' AlternateText="No image found" />
```

This showed the image fine but I wanted to do some JavaScript for clicking the imagebutton.

I understand you can't set the 'Click' property to be JavaScript but only code behind so I changed to a standard HTML `img`:

```
img alt="No image found" src='<%# "Images/" + Eval("CarMakeId") + ".jpg" %>'
                            onclick="openWindow('Test Message'); return false;" />
```

I can use the JavaScript to open the window but the image isn't being found for the `img.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by putting an asp:Image inside the link so didn't have to set the OnClientClick for an image button. Image is now part of the link and has the same event for the click of the link. Makes the code more maintainable also.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the attribute `runat="server"` to your `<img ... />` element.  This will then be available as an `HtmlImage` in your class, so if you declare it as `HtmlImage myimg`, you can set its source attribute in the class by `myimg.Src = "..."`.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm using this withing a Grid so I'm getting the CarMakeId from the grid element which could be different for each row. I think you're suggesting to set it in the code-behind? Am I correct in saying if I was setting it in the code-behind I wouldn't be able to set the CarMakeId?

Comment: In taht case you'll need to set it in the ItemDataBound event.  See this page for details: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ImageFromDBtoGrid.aspx